# minitest assert custom assertion fails

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I'm using custom assertions in my minitests and I want to unit test my assertions. Of course I can test the happy path but I want to assert that a test actually fails.

```
module Minitest
  module Assertions
    def assert_exists(value, msg = nil)
      assert(!value.to_s.empty?, msg)
    end
  end
end
```

In my test I want to write something like

```
describe 'Assertions' do
  it 'is empty' do
    assert_raises assert_exists('')
  end
end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this? (You need to specify the exception you are expecting, and pass the call as a block):

```
describe 'Assertions' do
  it 'is empty' do
    assert_raises(Minitest::Assertion) do
      assert_exists('')
    end
  end
end
```

This will include the call to `assert` in your `assert_raises` in the summary, which may not be exactly what you expect, but otherwise works.

Comment: So asserting that the assert raises for the assert fail would be going to far, I guess :)